# Change compiler path of Cython

Tags: python, cython

I'm writing a simple example to test Cython:

helloworld.pyx

```
def foo():
    print "hello cython world"
```

test_cython.py

```
import pyximport
pyximport.install()
import helloworld
helloworld.foo()
```

Which then returns:

```
ImportError: Building module testy failed:
["CompileError: command '/BAD_PATH/gcc' failed with exit status 1\n"]
```

The error had to do with Cython using a bad path to gcc.

Using "which gcc", I see my machine holds it in:

```
/CORRECT_PATH/gcc
```

Given I **can't** move gcc's location or write symlinks, are there any options in Cython to force it to use a different gcc location?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure (otherwise I'd post this as an answer...) but I think pyximport uses [distutils' setup.cfg](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/configfile.html) which you can specify a compiler in. I'd also check to see if you have any `CC` environmental variables set which are overriding the compiler.